# Home folder not shown as tilde (~) in bash prompt after changing user name

Tags: bash

I changed my user name (Ubuntu 22.04.1) from something to `user` by following the the exact steps in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/317008/282488). Everything seems to be fine as if the user name were created from scratch, except that the user prompt for bash does not use tilde (`~`).

When I initially launch a terminal (in GUI or without X server), the bash prompt is using `~` as before. But as soon as I `cd` some directory, it changes to the raw value, as shown below:

```
user@mybox:~$ cd 
user@mybox:/home/user$
```

*How can I fix the prompt to use tilde as it used to?*

FYI, the `~` still refers to the changed home folder correctly.
I didn't change the prompt in `.bashrc` or elsewhere. Below are the relevant info of the system:

```
$ getent passwd "$LOGNAME"
user:x:1000:1000:User:/home/user/:/bin/bash

$ echo "${HOME}"
/home/user/

$ echo "$PS1" 
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
```

Comment: Is this possibly fixed by simply removing the trailing `/` on the home directory in the `passwd` file?

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. Indeed, that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's the slash at the end of the home directory name that confuses Bash.

If I add one manually to my `$HOME`, Bash shows the full path of the home directory. Removing it again fixes it.

```
~$ pwd
/home/ilkkachu
~$ HOME=/home/ilkkachu/
/home/ilkkachu$ cd 
/home/ilkkachu$ HOME=/home/ilkkachu
~$
```

Try and remove the trailing slash from the path in the `passwd` entry.